# Where do I put the validator in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm learning to use Django and would like to validate the email address in the form submission.

This is my form code right now:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.core import validators
from first_app.models import FormSubmission
from django import forms

class SignupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FormSubmission
        fields ='__all__'
        def clean(self):
            all_clean_data = super().clean()
            email = all_clean_data['email']
            vmail = all_clean_data['verify_email']
```

and my models code

```
class FormSubmission(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    email = models.EmailField(unique= False)
    verify_email = models.EmailField(unique = False)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    #botcatcher = models.CharField(required=False,
                                 #widget = forms.HiddenInput,
                                 #validators=[validators.MaxLengthValidator(0)])


    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s"% (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Should the validator go in the models or the forms file?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to validate? Emails?

Comment: Yes I want to validate the emails before the user can submit them

Answer (score 0):

ModelForm itself will validate the data.
You can leave form like that:

```
class SignupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FormSubmission
        fields ='__all__
```

And to validate like that:

```
form = SignupForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    # do something
```

model form validation is triggered implicitly when calling is_valid()

If you need some custom validation, you can define method clean_, for example:

```
class SignupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FormSubmission
        fields ='__all__

    def clean_email(self):
         email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
         try:
             User.objects.get(email__iexact=email, is_active=True)
         except User.DoesNotExist:
             raise forms.ValidationError(
                 "Sorry, User with this email does not exists."
             )
         return email
```

See more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/